# Sharepoint 2013 - Wrap around text in list rich text column

Tags: rich-text

When using a rich text column on a custom list in Sharepoint 2013 I'm trying to place an image next to a paragraph, however only the first line is being placed next to the image, the rest goes on a new line and leaves a lot of empty space.

[image: text not being property wrapped around image.]

The position attribute doesn't seem to be doing much of anything, and because every paragraph gets surrounded by a `div` I'm having difficulties writing up a CSS that would allow me to do this.

I'm aware that I could just modify the inner HTML to achieve what I want, but I can't expect my end user to do so.

Is there a way to work around this?

Comment: Can you provide the code ?

Comment: @Ravi do you mean the HTML generated by SharePoint? This is simply a Rich Text column on a list